Streamlitで作成したWebアプリをデプロイしたが、iPhoneで表示されない。
赤ちゃんと遊ぶことを想定して、「ハンドレッド・シャボン・パーク」という名前のアプリを作成・デプロイしました。
Github: https://github.com/TomokiSegawa/Hundred_Bubble_Park
App URL: https://hundredbubblepark.streamlit.app/
PCでは上手く表示されたのですが、iPhoneで開こうとすると、Safari・Chromeいずれでも上手く表示されませんでした。
こちら、原因と解決策を教えていただけないでしょうか…。

追記: iPadのSafariでは、うまく動作しました。iPhoneでだけ動作しないようです…。

Pythonや Streamlitのバージョンなどの情報(PCと iPhoneそれぞれ) があったほうがよいのでは？
